# Permission issues while trying to compile native code

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, cygwin

While trying to build a application using android-ndk-r8d I am getting the following error message:

```
$ /cygdrive/d/Android_NDK/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build
Prebuilt : libffmpeg.so libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so
install: cannot open `./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so’ for reading: Permission denied
/cygdrive/d/Android_NDK/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/build/core/build-binary.mk:409: recipe for target `libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so’ failed
make: *** [libs/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Give the output of `ls -l ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libffmpeg.so`.

Comment: Can u please tell me the solution for this.?Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not enough information to tell a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The fix was to `chmod 777` (via cygwin) the problematic .so file in the `/obj/.../` dir.